# How to Subtracting sum of previous rows data from current row's data in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I have a table firebird which called t1 with 3 columns(week,date,amount).
I need to group data base on week column and

1. sum positive amount (stock)
2. sum negative amount (sold)
3. subtract stock (previous record) from sold(current record)

I attached a picture for t1 and t2

### t1:

```
week    date    amount
18/06/2016  14/06/2016  94
18/06/2016  15/06/2016  0
18/06/2016  16/06/2016  0
18/06/2016  17/06/2016  0
18/06/2016  18/06/2016  -1
25/06/2016  19/06/2016  -2
25/06/2016  20/06/2016  -1
25/06/2016  21/06/2016  0
25/06/2016  22/06/2016  -1
25/06/2016  23/06/2016  -1
25/06/2016  24/06/2016  -3
25/06/2016  25/06/2016  -1
02/07/2016  26/06/2016  -1
02/07/2016  27/06/2016  -2
02/07/2016  28/06/2016  0
02/07/2016  29/06/2016  1
02/07/2016  30/06/2016  0
02/07/2016  01/07/2016  -1
09/07/2016  03/07/2016  -1
09/07/2016  04/07/2016  -1
09/07/2016  05/07/2016  -2
09/07/2016  06/07/2016  0
09/07/2016  07/07/2016  -2
09/07/2016  08/07/2016  -1
09/07/2016  09/07/2016  -3
```

---

t2:

```
week      sold     stock
          null      94
18/06/2016  1       93
25/06/2016  9       84
02/07/2016  3       81
09/07/2016  9       72
```

---

i'm using Firebird and I final script should be run in firebird or standard sql
thanks

[image]

Comment: This is not a SQL writing service, people here would rather help you improve something that you already tried. Please include some query that you already wrote to try to solve this problem or at least some links that you read while researching how to do an SQL `SELECT` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you use Firebird 3, you can look at [window functions](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query would seem to be:

```
select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
       sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold
from t1
group by week;
```

Firebird doesn't support window functions, but you can use a correlated subquery as well.  A CTE helps.  I think it is:

```
with t as (
      select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
             sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold
      from t1
      group by week
     )
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.stock) + sum(t2.sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.week <= t.week
       ) as stock
from t;
```

EDIT:

With window functions (in Firebird 3) this is even easier:

```
select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
       sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold,
       sum(amount) over (order by week) as 
from t1
group by week;
```

Comment: Firebird 3 supports window functions.

Comment: unfortunately Firebird version is 2.5 and  

with t as (
      select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
             sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold
      from t1
      group by week
     )
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.stock) + sum(t2.sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.week <= t.week
       ) as stock
from t;

-------

and 

select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
       sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold
from t1
group by week;


Doesn't work !!

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for your help -- it's work fine**

with t as (
      select week, sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as stock,
             sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sold
      from t1
      group by week
     )
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.stock) + sum(t2.sold)
        from t t2
        where t2.week <= t.week
       ) as stock
from t;